# QTimer::singleShot(..) inside connect(..) function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to update the background of my game after 10 seconds. I used `singleShot` function of QTimer inside the connect function. It does work correctly for the first time but after the first call, update background function is being called after every 1 second (or so). I am new to Qt, please excuse my ignorance.
Here is the relevant code :

```
void Scene::setUpPillarTimer(QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixItem)
{
    QTimer *backgroundTimer = new QTimer();

    int durationOfPillar = 0;
  
    pillarTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(pillarTimer, &QTimer::timeout,this, [=]()mutable{
        PillarItem *pillarItem = new PillarItem(durationOfPillar);

        addItem(pillarItem);

        backgroundTimer->singleShot(10000, this, [=](){
            updateBackground(pixItem);
        });

    });

    pillarTimer->start(800);

}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `pillarTimer` triggers every 800ms and installs a singleshot timer every time?

Comment: Oh, So a new `singleShot` timer is made every 800 ms. right ? @Botje

Comment: Any other way to call `updateBackground` every 10 seconds? @Botje

Comment: Just create a regular QTimer with timeout 10000.

Comment: ok will see. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I removed the `singleShot` function and inserted simple `connect` function with a timeout 100000 ms.

```
void Scene::setUpPillarTimer(QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixItem)
{
    QTimer *backgroundTimer = new QTimer(this);

    int durationOfPillar = 0;


    connect(backgroundTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [=](){
        updateBackground(pixItem);
        

    });
    backgroundTimer->start(10000);

    pillarTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(pillarTimer, &QTimer::timeout,this, [=]()mutable{
        PillarItem *pillarItem = new PillarItem(durationOfPillar);
        addItem(pillarItem);



    });

    pillarTimer->start(800);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are looking for because your code is showing two different timers. Using a signle QTimer would be best but again I don't understand the original requirement for the 800 msec timer.

```
void Scene::setUpPillarTimer(QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixItem)
{
    QTimer *backgroundTimer = new QTimer();
    backgroundTimer->setInterval(10000); //msec

    connect(backgroundTimer, &QTimer::timeout,this, [=]()mutable{
        // Here this is executed every 10 seconds
        PillarItem *pillarItem = new PillarItem(durationOfPillar);

        addItem(pillarItem);

        updateBackground(pixItem);
        });

    });

    backgroundTimer->start();

}
```

Comment: The other timer (`pillarTimer`) is to add new pillar every 800 ms., and `backgroundTimer` is to update the background every 10 seconds. I have solved the problem by creating to separate `connect` function.